# else statement doesn't seem to execute

Tags: jquery

i'm a complete begginner and was hoping to get some help on my first script.

basically i want one link that when clicked makes a div slide down and changes the links text, when its clicked again the process reverses.

here is my code:

```
$(function() {
if ($('#link1:contains("link text")')) {
        $('#link1').click(function() {
            $('#div1').slideDown(2000);
            $('#link1').text('hide div 1');
        }); 
}
else {
        $('#link1').click(function() {
            $('#div1').slideUp(2000);
            $('#link1').text('link text');
        }); 
}
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks guys.

Answer (score 7):

`if ($('#link1:contains("link text")')) {` will always be true.  Jquery will always return an object.  What you need to change it to is:

```
if ($('#link1:contains("link text")').length>0) {
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$function(){
    $('#link1').click(function() {
        if($('#link1:contains("link text")').length){
            $('#div1').slideDown(2000);
            $(this).text('hide div 1');
        } else {
            $('#div1').slideUp(2000);
            $(this).text('link text');
        }
    });
});
```

As I understood it, you need to evaluate the text every time you click the button. This'll do it.

Answer (score 1):

An `Object` is *truthy* in JavaScript. You need to expose something that can be truthy *or* falsy.

If checking if a jQuery object has matched any elements, check the `length` property.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you want the first selection to return no elements.

In jQuery, even when no elements are selected, it still returns an empty array, and `!![]` is true, so it doesn't run the else, because the if is true.

What you should try is

```
if ($('#link1:contains("link text")')[0]) {
    ...
```

because if no elements are found, the first value will be undefined, which evaluates to false.

Comment: jQuery never returns an array when used like that. It returns an array like `Object`.

Comment: @alex Nobody cares about specifics like that.

Comment: @tyler They will if they try to call `Array` methods on it, such as `pop()`.

Comment: @alex I thought it inherited from Array.. Apparently not.. Thanks for making me test/realize that. :)

Comment: @tyler We are programmers, specifics are *very* important :)

Comment: @alex I know Sizzle returns an actual array, so I always figured jQuery did too, seeing as they use it internally and play a heavy part in development.. xD This is why I made my own. Haha. Other people do it awkwardly.